# Electromagnetically launching a model glider

Tags: design

As a hobby project, I'm wondering if it would be plausible to build a small, unpowered R/C glider that's launched at high speed (20-60 m/s, or maybe more) from the ground and then manipulated once it's in the air, sort of like the [winch launches used in competitive gliding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliding#Winch_launching), but with all the acceleration happening on a short track on the ground.

Setting aside designing the glider (though I'm sure making a piece of plastic survive 50-100 gees will be a fun process), what could I use to launch this thing? I want to make the length of the track that'll accelerate the airplane under 2 meters. (mostly because I think it would be cooler, this is a hobby project after all)

I've done some back-of-the-envelope calculations with liberal estimates for the weight of the glider and exit speed, and it seems like I'd need to deliver around 10 J to the glider in 1/30th of a second, which seems feasible even with the single-digit efficiency of a coil- or railgun. My question is: how would I deliver that? I know I just mentioned coilguns, but I'm not sure how to use a similar principle to propel an object larger than the width of the barrel. Same goes for using compressed air or combustible gases.

Comment: use a rubber band

Comment: I feel dumb for not thinking of that first

Comment: it's not a case of being dumb ... it is a case of past experience ... I've heard of full size gliders, with a pilot, being launched by a bundle of rubber bands

Comment: you're probably right, and thanks for that. out of curiosity, do you know if there's a video/pictures of that launch?

Comment: It's called a bungee launch. Basically a 20-30 foot long sling shot (surgical tubing-like) band staked into the ground. It's long so you don't destroy the plane the same way a mass driver needs to be long to not turn humans inside into mush. There are much shorter ones on frames/rails but of they are for EDF jets with engines and short strong wings, not for sailplanes. My favorite is discus launch, but 2m is too long for that unless you're 12 feet tall.

Comment: The track only needs to be as long as the glider: https://youtu.be/848By5koOcY

Comment: @Rob The onboard rocket is doing all the launching there and provides thrust for much longer distance than the rails are long so it doesn't count.

Comment: @DKNguyen, this would probably be more helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/217953/142621

Comment: A bungee launch is also called a hi-start launch.

Comment: @asolidtime I do not have a video ... it's a story my father told me ... from his description, the elastics were square in cross-section and were quite long ... there were few dozen of them in a bundle ... a winch was used to stretch the bundle ... the glider was hooked and then the bundle was released ... i think that they were launching from a hilltop into a valley ... he did mention that some of the pilots were skilled enough to catch the thermals above the valley

Comment: @asolidtime one thing I just remembered ... when I was a child, we used to launch unpowered model airplanes like a kite ... the string had a metal ring on the end ... the ring would engage with a rear-facing hook on the underside of the plane ... when the plane was high enough, it would overtake the person that was pulling the string and the metal ring would unhook

Answer (score 1):

An Electromagnetic Aircraft Launch System ([EMALS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_Aircraft_Launch_System#Advantages)) system, which is essentially a linear induction motor, is practical. It propels a carriage along a track to launch the aircraft. The associated weight remains on the ground, the additional weight on the glider would consist of only a launching hook.
[image: EMALS -]

- The EMALS is considered to be more efficient than a railgun due to the fact that railguns require much higher system powers, because roughly similar energies must be delivered in a few milliseconds, as opposed to a few seconds for an EMALS, also the linear induction motor is more efficient than an open rail.
- A railgun would require a metallic glider, or at least a magnetic payload which must be carried with the plane after launch; unless it is ejected.
- The barrel on the railgun would have to be replaced after about a dozen or two dozen shots are fired. An EMALS has much lower wear, though the [reliability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_Aircraft_Launch_System#Reliability) rate is still lower than desired.
- A [coilgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun) would also be more efficient than a railgun, since the electromagnetic field surrounds the projectile.

An efficient glider would be constructed of lightweight materials, in the shape of an aerodynamic glider, the metallic portion (unless ejectable) is dead weight.

A railgun's projectile must be metallic, the heavier and more compact the better, lending itself to balls or dart shaped projectiles. The entirety of the projectile (except for fins) is useful weight, to impact the target.

[Railgun video](https://youtu.be/Q1VXEGJkBsE)

[EMALS video](https://youtu.be/DeJBaFzl77Q?t=110)